# Extra semicolon showing up in axios get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to dynamically build an axios get request, and have currently hardcoded some values in my parameters array to test with like so:

```
const parameters = [
    'table=cumulative',
    'where=koi_disposition like \'CANDIDATE\' and koi_period>300 and koi_prad<2',
    'order=koi_period',
    'format=json'
];
let searchParameters = '';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/nstedAPI/nph-nstedAPI'
});

for (let element in parameters) {
    if (element !== '') {
        searchParameters += `?${parameters[element]}`;
    }
}
```

I then add this query to my axios get request below:

```
export const getExoplanets = async () => {
    try {
        searchParameters = searchParameters.replace(/;/g, "");
        console.log(`${searchParameters}`);
        return await api.get(`${searchParameters}`);
        // return await api.get(`?table=cumulative&where=koi_disposition like 'CANDIDATE' and koi_period>300 and koi_prad<2&order=koi_period&format=json`);
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
};
```

When the variable version runs the api returns the error:

ERROR
Error Type: UserError
Message:    Constraint contains an illegal keyword: ";"

However when the commented out, hard coded version runs it works just fine. At some point an extra semicolon is being added to the request. I assume it is being added at the end, but I can't find where or how. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `for..in` to iterate arrays

Comment: You are also appending a `?` to each parameter. Are you sure the semicolon is in your request values, and not some issue in the backend since you are getting a response back? Can you share what the request and response is from the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Axios supports easy query parameters using the `params` config option.

Just provide an object of key / value pairs and Axios will do all the encoding for you

```js
const params = {
  table: "cumulative",
  where: "koi_disposition like 'CANDIDATE' and koi_period>300 and koi_prad<2",
  order: "koi_period",
  format: "json"
}

return api.get("", { params })
// or return api.get("", { params: params })
```

This will send a request to

```
?table=cumulative&where=koi_disposition+like+%27CANDIDATE%27+and+koi_period%3E300+and+koi_prad%3C2&order=koi_period&format=json
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I implemented this and it fixed the original problem, but it is still not working as it should. Now I get the response: 

Error Type: UserError - "table" parameter<br>
Message:    "" is not a valid table. 

It works if I hardcode it, it works if I pass in the parameters as variables to the url string, but any attempt to pass the parameters array as actual parameters fails. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Brandon are you sure you're sending a value for the `table` parameter?

Comment: I am passing it exactly as you outlined above. 
const parameters = {
 table: 'cumulative',
 where: 'koi_disposition like \'CANDIDATE\' and koi_period>300 and koi_prad<2',
 order: 'koi_period',
 format: 'json'
};

const api = axios.create({
 baseURL: 'https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/nstedAPI/nph-nstedAPI'
});

export const getExoplanets = async () => {
 try {
  return await api.get('', { parameters });
   } catch (error) {
  return error;
 }
};

Comment: @Brandon The Axios configuration property is named `params`, not `parameters`

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you! I though that was just a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

it seem you having an issue in this bellow line you have used the `\` rest of this you can wrap all the things in the double quote.

```
'where=koi_disposition like \'CANDIDATE\' and koi_period>300 and koi_prad<2',

"where=koi_disposition like 'CANDIDATE' and koi_period>300 and koi_prad<2",
```